# Firefox add-ons and page HTML content change events (Google Reader)

Tags: html, ajax, firefox-addon, gecko

I am new to Firefox add-on development and planning to write a Firefox Mobile add-on which would optimize some page content to be more suitable for viewing on mobile devices.

I have studied how to create an add-on which intercepts page load events...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads

... and this is quite straightforward for this far.

However, I'd also like to interact with HTML content which is loaded / displayed outside the normal HTML load chain. This would be namely Google Reader content which Google Reader fetches using AJAX.

Does Firefox provide any hooks to post-process content injected to pages via innerHTML and such? Also, as an alternative I have been thinking about capturing click/touch events and rerun the processing after each event: when you click an article in Google Reader it will open a new view containing the article content.

How other add-ons generally do this?

Answer (score 1):

The XUL School and the XUL Tutorial content on MDC will help you get an understanding of how to use XUL to build user interfaces. The MDC Code Snippets section has code samples showing some of the APIs available to add-on developers.

One thing you should note is that Firefox Mobile is a multi-process application: The UI is in the main process and the web content (the tabs) are all in a second, child process. This is different than Firefox Desktop, which is a single process application.

We have some notes on how to build multi-process add-ons [1] and I made some video tutorials [2] to help as well.

Interacting with web content in Firefox Mobile means you need to create a script that runs in the child process. The script has direct access to the webpage's DOM window and DOM document. If your add-on has UI, you will use messages to communicate between the two processes. The links [1] and [2] give details on how to do both DOM interaction and sending messages.

Listening for post-load content injection is tricky. You have no additional hooks beyond those a normal webpage would use. You could use polling (check for changes using a setInterval) or you could listen for DOM mutation events (which are bad for performance).

Firefox Mobile developers hangout on Mozilla's IRC in the #mobile channel.

[1] https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Extensions/Electrolysis

[2] http://people.mozilla.com/~mfinkle/tutorials/